# How can we classify a post on a blog as being inappropriate for underage readers say 16?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, text-classification

Update: How would one approach the task of classifying any text on public forums such as Games, or blogs such that derogatory comments/texts before bring posted are filtered.

Original: "
I want to filter out adult content from tweets (or any text for that matter).

For spam detection, we have datasets that check whether a particular text is spam or ham.

For adult content, I found a dataset I want to use (extract below):

```
arrBad = [
'acrotomophilia',
'anal',
'anilingus',
'anus',
.
. etc.
.
'zoophilia']
```

**Question**

How can I use that dataset to filter text instances?
"

Comment: A liberterian way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would approach this as a Text Classification problem, because using blacklists of words typically does not work very well to classify full texts. The main reason why blacklists don't work is that you will have a lot of false positives (one example: your list contains the word 'sexy', which alone isn't enough to flag a document as being for adults). To do so you need a training set with documents tagged as being "adult content" and others "safe for work". So here is what I would do:

1. check whether an existing labelled dataset can be used. You need
   several thousands of documents of each class.
2. If you don't find any, create one. For instance you can create a scraper and download Reddit content. Read for instance [Text Classification of NSFW Reddit Posts](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nando/540-2013/projects/p38.pdf)
3. Build a text classifier with NLTK. If you don't know how, read: [Learning to Classify Text](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html)

Answer (score 1):

This can be treated as a binary text classification problem. You should collect documents that contain 'adult-content' as well as documents that do not contain adult content ('universal'). It may so happen that a word/phrase that you have included in the list arrBad may be present in the 'universal' document, for example, 'girl on top' in the sentence 'She wanted to be the first girl on top of Mt. Everest.' You need to get a count vector of the number of times each word/phrase occurs in a 'adult-content' document and a 'universal' document.

I'd suggest you consider using algorithms like Naive Bayes (which should work fairly well in your case). However, if you want to capture the context in which each phrase is used, you could consider the Support Vector Machines algorithm as well (but that would involve tweaking a lot of complex parameters).

Comment: Personally I prefer using sklearn for text classification, compared to NLTK.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in something like [TextRazor](https://www.textrazor.com/). By using their API you could be able to classify the input text.

And for example you can choose to remove all input texts thats comes with some of the categories or keywords you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you more need to explore on filtering algorithms, studying their usage, how multi pattern searching works and how you can use some of those algorithms (their implementations are free online, so it is not hard to find an existing implementation and customize for your needs). Some pointers can be.

> 1. Check how grep family of algorithm works, especially the bitap algorithm and Wu-Manber implementation for fgrep..Depending upon how accurate you want to be, it may require adding some fuzzy logic handling (think why people use fukc instead of fuck..right?).
> 2. You may find Bloom Filter interesting, since it wont have any false negatives (your data set), downside is that it may contain false positives..